# How can I get a discord bot to send a message if a command is said?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a discord bot using Python but none of the commands that should be running are running. I've traced it down to the if command below:

```
  if message.content.startswith("$hello"): # <<<<<< This command is causing issues!
    print("Command detected: $hello")
    await message.channel.send('Hello there! I am a bot. Thats it.')
```

$hello is supposed to say in the chat  "Hello there! I am a bot. Thats it."
However, the if command doesnt work, and even if $hello is said, it doesn't run what it is supposed to.

Here is the entire code itself:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents(messages=True))


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print("Message detected.")
  if message.author == client.user:
    print("Returning...")
    return
  print("User message confirmed to not be a bot.")
  if message.content.startswith("$hello"): #<<< This is causing issues!
    print("Command detected: $hello")
    await message.channel.send('Hello there! I am a bot. Thats it.')

# imagine there is a run command here, with the token
# im not putting it here since its a security risk
# the run bot command works
```

I've tried using different types of commands, like startswith and == contains but it doesn't print the hello message. Anyone got any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intents.messages` is not the same as `Intents.message_content`!

[messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.messages):

> Whether guild and direct message related events are enabled.
>
> This is a shortcut to set or get both guild_messages and dm_messages.

[message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content):

> Whether message content, attachments, embeds and components will be available in messages

You're missing `message_content`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been troubleshooting for days, you've helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

````py
import discord
import os
#make sure to set up your command syntax and set your intents so the bot can read messages
client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.remove_command("help")


#don't use on_message for commands, it's gonna cause problems.
#instead, use the command funtion here
@client.command()
async def command(ctx):
    ctx.channel.send("command is working!")

client.run("token")
``` that should work
````

Comment: Don't post codeblocks without an exlpanation or answer. Also, don't use `Intents.all()` when you don't need to. Subscribe to the intents that you actually want.